# How to make the guess counter not go up when user guesses correctly, also everytime the user gets the guess incorrect it generates a new selection?

Tags: python, spyder

I am generally new to coding, so this could be easy to some, but I find it confusing. I am making a code that uses a collection of dry and wet food with number of brands, then will randomly generate a combination. The cat will randomly decide if they want 4 - 6 feedings. Give the user 4-5 times to make a mistake. Correct selections do not count against the guess counter. However, every time the user guesses incorrect it makes a new random selection.
Here's what I have so far

```
import random

collection = {
    "Wet" : [1,2,3,4],
    "Dry" : [1,2,3,4]
}

def foodSelect(collection):
    feedingsNum = random.choice([4,5,6]) 
    feedingCount = 1 

    while(feedingCount != feedingsNum):
        collectionChoice = random.choice(['Wet','Dry'])
        brandChoice = random.choice(collection[collectionChoice])
        userGuess(collectionChoice,brandChoice) 
        feedingCount+=1

def userGuess(collectionChoice,brandChoice):
    while True:
        collectionGuess = input('Wet or Dry? Make your guess: ')
        foodGuess = input('Guess the food brand: ')
        if (collectionGuess == 'Wet' or collectionGuess == 'Dry') and foodGuess.isdigit():
            break;
        else:
            print("Enter valid guesses! ")
    
    poppinsMeal = 0 
    
    if collectionGuess == collectionChoice:
        if int(foodGuess) == brandChoice:
            poppinsMeal+=1 
            print('Your guess is correct')
           
        else:
            poppinsMeal+=(1/2) 
            print('Need a bit more luck')
    else:
        print('Oops! Guess Mr.Poppins is not eating :(') 

    print(poppinsMeal)

foodSelect(collection)
```

I am having difficulty with the correct selection not counting against the guess counter, also the random guessing after incorrect. I know this is a lot but if anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you consider to be the guess counter?  You should only decrement the guess counter when the guess is incorrect!

Comment: The whole point is for the user to guess what food the cat wants. The cat wants to be feed 4-6 times. And the user gets 4 to 5 guesses, so if its correct he gets to guess again to know what else the cat wants

Answer (score 0):

`userGuess()` should return a value that indicates whether the user guessed correctly. Then you can use this so you only increment `feedingCount` when it's wrong.

```
import random

collection = {
    "Wet" : [1,2,3,4],
    "Dry" : [1,2,3,4]
}

def foodSelect(collection):
    feedingsNum = random.choice([4,5,6]) 
    feedingCount = 1 

    while(feedingCount != feedingsNum):
        collectionChoice = random.choice(['Wet','Dry'])
        brandChoice = random.choice(collection[collectionChoice])
        if not userGuess(collectionChoice,brandChoice):
            feedingCount+=1

def userGuess(collectionChoice,brandChoice):
    correctGuess = False
    while True:
        collectionGuess = input('Wet or Dry? Make your guess: ')
        foodGuess = input('Guess the food brand: ')
        if (collectionGuess == 'Wet' or collectionGuess == 'Dry') and foodGuess.isdigit():
            break;
        else:
            print("Enter valid guesses! ")
    
    poppinsMeal = 0 
    
    if collectionGuess == collectionChoice:
        if int(foodGuess) == brandChoice:
            poppinsMeal+=1 
            print('Your guess is correct')
            correctGuess = True
        else:
            poppinsMeal+=(1/2) 
            print('Need a bit more luck')
    else:
        print('Oops! Guess Mr.Poppins is not eating :(') 

    print(poppinsMeal)
    return correctGuess

foodSelect(collection)
```